# R/dplyr: Assign value to a group base on one column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this data set:

```
test <- data.frame("eventId" = c(rep(1,5), rep(2,3), rep(3,6)), 
          "commandType" = c(rep("RO",3), rep("RW", 2), rep("RO",7),"RW", "RO"), 
          "sessionType" =  c(rep("RW",5), rep("RO",3), rep("RW",6)))
```

I want to assign `sessionType` for each `eventId` (group) based on `commandType`. If there’s an occurance of “RW” in the group, that whole group would be asssigned w “RW”. If the group only have “RO” or “RW” as `commandType`, the `sessionType` would match the `commandType`.

I’m thinking this can be done in `dplyr` but not sure how to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use `group_by` in `dplyr`...

```
test <- test %>% 
  group_by(eventId) %>% 
  mutate(sessionType2 = ifelse("RW" %in% commandType, "RW", commandType))

test
   eventId commandType sessionType sessionType2
     <dbl> <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       
 1       1 RO          RW          RW          
 2       1 RO          RW          RW          
 3       1 RO          RW          RW          
 4       1 RW          RW          RW          
 5       1 RW          RW          RW          
 6       2 RO          RO          RO          
 7       2 RO          RO          RO          
 8       2 RO          RO          RO          
 9       3 RO          RW          RW          
10       3 RO          RW          RW          
11       3 RO          RW          RW          
12       3 RO          RW          RW          
13       3 RW          RW          RW          
14       3 RO          RW          RW
```

By the way, I also had to set `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in your dataframe code.

Comment: In case you would like to do multiple checks which could result in nested `if_else` statements, you can also use `case_when`.